# Middle click using IBM/Lenovo keyboard with TrackPoint to scroll on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scrolling, trackpoint

I have an IBM ThinkPad style USB keyboard with TrackPoint (similar to the ones Lenovo currently sells).  I love this keyboard and would like to use it with a Mac OS X machine I have.  Everything seems to work, except that middle clicking doesn't let me scroll.  Mac OS X is, however, receiving the middle click from the keyboard because in some programs, like Chrome, it registers the middle click and acts differently.  How can I get middle clicking to put me into "scroll-mode" in all programs on the OS?

(I'm aware that some programs, like Firefox, have extensions to support this.  I want a more complete solution, though, especially since the main things I do with this computer aren't Web browsing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [usboverdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/)

Comment: that works, although I wish there were a solution that didn't involve shareware.

Comment: After installing you must do some configuration: Choose `Settings` tab in the configuration window, then choose `Middle Button` and select action `Move To Scroll`.

Comment: @Tarrasch thanks for the post-installation setup info. Someone recommended controllermate to me for setting this up, but this is definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scroll function by clicking middle button through the App. "Smart Scroll" (link: http://www.marcmoini.com/sx_en.html)